# Connecting Hive Tables using SqlContext

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, hive

My question might sound silly for most of you but i need to do some operations in my hive table using spark-scala, for that i want to know is there anyway i can use `SqlContext` to read hive tables. I know about `HiveContext` but i want to use **SqlContext**.

Comment: It looks to me like the Spark documentation explains exactly this: http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/sql-programming-guide.html#hive-tables - ie you create a `SqlContext` from a `HiveContext`.

Comment: I read that documentation but somehow i think i missed reading it. So basically `HiveContext` is inheriting from `SQLContext` so we are using SQLContext only. am i correct ?

Comment: am i correct @BinaryNerd ?

Comment: `HiveContext` just extends `SqlContext` as you can see in the code: https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/hive/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/hive/HiveContext.scala

Comment: Thanks @BinaryNerd it is really helpfull

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As *@Binary Nerd* mentioned in comment:

> `HiveContext` extends `SQLContext`

So when you use a type safe language(Java), you could declare your `SQLContext` in this way:

```
SQLContext sqlContext = new HiveContext(sc)
```